# PHP connect with MSSQL extremely slow

Tags: php, sql

So I finally got my website working with Microsoft SQL Express 2012. But just connecting to the server already takes 15-20 seconds.

```
    sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

That's what I'm currently using. If I remove that line it takes like 0.000040 seconds...
This is only connecting, I'm not even querying a database yet LOL!

Comment: Do you have access to your `php.ini` file? Can you disable `php_mysqli.dll` or `mysqli.so` (the `mysqli` extension). There are multiple reported issues with it causing long connect delays for MSSQL

Comment: Yeah, I'm hosting this website myself but I just tried what you said but that only gave me like a 2-3 second less load time..

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried enabling `PDO` and `PDO_SQLSRV` and see if it changes anything?

Comment: You mean just enabling the pdo .dll extensions?

Comment: Yeah, and switching your code to use PDO instead of the regular `sqlsrv` library

Comment: I cannot get that to work :S

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my linux box was slow on resolving.
This is what helped me:

```
sqlsrv_connect( $IP, $connectionInfo);
```

I changed my mysql.example.com to 1.1.1.1 and now everything is working fast